# How can you say “rule by gods” without a church involved?

Tags: single-word-requests

Somebody I know online has been writing a story where he’d like to name the system where gods rule, but a church isn’t involved. He used “deiocracy,” but we both agreed that’s one, made up, and two, a hircocervus monstrosity of Latin and Greek together. Are there any words that can be used for rule by gods, but not by their church?

Comment: Hello, Rob. This question is related to yours: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38505/what-do-you-call-a-government-when-the-rulers-are-gods

Comment: Shoot, I didn’t see that, did I? I did some searching and basic research but that didn’t turn up. Could someone delete this for me?

Comment: I can't delete your question-- I'm new here myself, and don't have those powers or know the procedure. I believe that first questions get checked out by a moderator sooner or later; if you aren't allowed to delete your own question as per https://www.bleepingworld.com/delete-question-on-stack-overflow/, I guess you just wait and see what happens to it... Cheers anyhow, and welcome!

Comment: I can help out by voting to close your question as a duplicate. In doing so though, I want to echo @Conrado: Cheers and welcome!

Comment: It did, but the top answer wasn’t the one I was looking for, I liked “thearchy,” though.

Comment: The system posted this comment when I voted to close ...

Comment: Ah, I apologize.